# In file reading, how to skip the Nth first lines

Tags: c, fseek

I have written a program to read the X, Y and Z coordinates of a molecule from a file (input.xyz) and do some task. However, 
I want my program to skip the first two lines as my input file 
has the following structure:

```
3 
water 
O      -0.73692879      -1.68212007      -0.00000000 
H       0.03427635      -1.68212007      -0.59075946 
H      -1.50813393      -1.68212007      -0.59075946
```

I have used the following section in my code

```
fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
fseek(fptr,3,SEEK_SET);
for(i=0;i<Atom_num;i++)
{
   X[i] = Y[i] = Z[i] = 0;
   fscanf(fptr,"%2s%lf%lf%lf",Atom[i].symbol,&X[i],&Y[i],&Z[i]);
   printf("%2s\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n",Atom[i].symbol,X[i],Y[i],Z[i]);
}
fclose(fptr);
```

Where Atom_num is the first line of input.xyz

However, printf shows the following output

```
at  0.000000    0.000000    0.000000 
er  0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  
O   -0.736929   -1.682120   -0.000000
```

I do not know why fseek() is not working. 
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You can read each line with `fgets` and extract its information with `sscanf`. That way you can simply skip as many lines as you wish. Don't use `fseek`.

Comment: Add `if(i > 1)` before the `printf`?

Comment: `fseek` doesn't position the file pointer to the nth line but to the nth byte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the signature of fseek():

```
int fseek(FILE *stream, long int offset, int whence)
```

especially at the definition of **offset**

> offset − This is the number of bytes to offset from whence.

So when you do:

```
fseek(fptr,3,SEEK_SET);
```

you just skip 3 bytes in the input file.

What you want to do is something like this:

```
char line[256]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) /* read a line */
{
    if (count == lineNumber)
    {
        //Your code regarding this line and on, 
          or maybe just exit this while loop and 
          continue reading the file from this point.
    }
    else
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, consider using (on implementations having them) [getline(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) or [readline(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html)

Comment: I was wondering what line[256] mean? Does it mean 256 characters of a line?

Comment: Yes, this is just some random value. I assumed no more than 256 chars on a single line, so I made the buffer for reading a line this size.

Answer (score 2):

#### -- fgets() Approach --

this can be done with fgets.
from man7.org: see here [fgets](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html)

The `fgets()` function shall read `bytes` from `stream` into the array
pointed to by `s` in our case pointed by `line`, until `n−1 bytes` are read, or a `<newline>` is read and transferred to `line`, or an `end-of-file,  EOF` condition is encountered. The string is then terminated with a `null` byte.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LINES_TO_SKIP   3
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 120

int main () {
   FILE *fp;
   char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];  /*assuming that your longest line doesnt exceeds MAX_LINE_LENGTH */
   int line_c = 0;

   /* opening file for reading */
   fp = fopen("file.txt" , "r");
   if(fp == NULL) 
   {
      perror("Error opening file");
      return(-1);
   }
   
   while(( fgets (line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fp)!=NULL )
   {
      if(line_c < LINES_TO_SKIP)
      {
        ++line_c;
        puts("Skiped line");
      }
      else
      {
        /*
         ... PROCESS The lines...
       */
      } 
   }
   
   fclose(fp);
   
   return(0);
}
```